# how to return all events with the same name from dataLayer using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data-layers

My website has several checkout events corresponding to different stages of the purchase stage (i.e., review order, add personal details, add payment info). Each is called 'checkout' in the data layer. I want to return a list of all the events in the dataLayer called 'checkout' - so I can compare them.

I can search for individual events by their sequence number

```
window.dataLayer[245];
window.dataLayer[288];
```

and I can search by name

```
window.dataLayer.find(x => x.event === "checkout");
```

however, searching by name only returns the first event called 'checkout', I want to return all three, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method of Array instances returns the ***first element*** in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

To return all events with the name *checkout* try [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method of Array instances creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
const checkoutEvents = window.dataLayer.filter(x => x.event === "checkout");
```